# Where do these constructor parameters come from in this inversion of control instantiation?

Tags: c#, constructor, inversion-of-control, resolve

I'm working on an incomplete application in WPF/C#. Most of it is very well coded, though as I didn't know about Inversion of Control beforehand it puzzled me for a while. Now I think I've figured it out some, but some things still stump me.

Case in point: we have this great big class called `CoreApplication` that manages everything general. Among other things, it has a series of `RegisterType` instructions, among which

```
SharedObjects.InversionOfControl.RegisterType<IGoodClass, GoodClass>();
```

(`SharedObjects` being a static class that defines, among other things, a static `IUnityContainer` object named `InversionOfControl`, initialized with new `UnityContainer()` at declaration.)

Elsewhere in `CoreApplication`, there is an `ICommand` that includes the code

```
var goodClassForNavigation = (SharedObjects.InversionOfControl.Resolve<IGoodClass>());
```

Which, I understand, calls the constructor of `GoodClass`, since `Register()` linked `IGoodClass` and `GoodClass` and `Resolve()` was called with `IGoodClass`.

Fine. Now, going to `GoodClass` to understand what it does, I see that its constructor looks like this:

```
public GoodClass(CoreApplication coreApplication)
{
    this.coreApplication = coreApplication;
    // Other stuff happens
}
```

I've made sure that the parameter was duly instantiated; various properties and fields of it have the values I'd expect.

What I cannot understand is, where does this `CoreApplication` parameter come from?

I tried to look up the constructor in `GoodClass`'s base classes, but they have no explicit one.

Thanks to those who still are with me so far. What is happening? Where does the constructor take its parameter from? Is it from the class the constructor is called in? From something in `SharedObjects.InversionOfControl`?

Comment: `CoreApplication` is resolved by your DI framework automagically and then the instance is passed to the constructor. How this works highly depends on the DI framework you are using.

Comment: The constructor needs to be called... by something. What that something is can be anything... I would suggest you put a breakpoint in the constructor, and check the stack trace when it hits. You should be able to get a grasp of where it's coming from that way

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: the application uses UnityContainer. Does this help or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @musefan: you are quite right, of course. When I did that, I saw that the call was that `Resolve<IGoodClass>()` line quoted above.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz: I guess if you are using a Microsoft framework its not as simple the way I suggested... I thought it was all your own classes

Comment: What is the type of `SharedObjects.InversionOfControl`? It if's anything that ends in "container" then it may be using your DI container as a service locator. Wait... `CoreApplication` contains the DI container setup, and then `CoreApplication` is itself being injected into other classes?

Comment: @Scott Hannen: as stated above, it's `UnityContainer`. Which is, as I understand it, the DI container. It *isn't* created in `CoreApplication`, but there is a `SharedObjects.InversionOfControl.RegisterInstance(this)`in `CoreApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your DI framework does the heavy lifting:

1. you call Resolve(), a method of your DI framework
2. the DI framework now resolves `IGoodClass` to `GoodClass`
3. the DI framework analyses the constructor and sees that a parameter is needed
4. the DI famework now tries to resolve a parameter instance based on the parameter type, in your case `CoreApplication`
5. the DI framework creates and instance of `CoreApplication`
6. the DI framework now can create an instance of `GoodClass` by passing the resolved instance of `CoreApplication` to the constructor

The resolution process can be configured, for example with *registration by convention*.

I suggest you read the article [Dependency Injection with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx).

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! 

Now, as I mentioned, the instance of CoreApplication has actual, non-default values that cannot come from mere instantiation (such as a UserName which contains the login I entered at startup). 

Hence my suspicion that the CoreApplication passed to the constructor is the one in which the interface IGoodClass is resolved. But why and how? Does the DI framework actually look around at the objects at hand? I felt those steps 4 to 6 to be awfully smart - or chancy - on the framework's behalf, but that would be pushing it further.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz You can configure Unity in a way that specific parameters are filled with specific instances. For example there are various overloads of `RegisterType()`. You need to find the place where Unity is configured to get the info you need.